# Java - Printing an object from an arraylist

Tags: java, class, oop, object, arraylist

I've defined an object and then created numerous objects from a filescanner. I've done this by having a while loop keep adding these objects into an ArrayList to store them for later use.

I'm now trying to print out said object as a string, the issue I'm finding is it has various attributes (int, string, double, boolean, boolean, boolean).

Below is the object:

```
    class Room {
    int roomNumber;
    String roomType;
    double roomPrice;
    boolean roomBalcony;
    boolean roomLounge;
    boolean roomReserved;

    public Room(int roomNumber, String roomType, double roomPrice, boolean roomBalcony, boolean roomLounge, boolean roomReserved) {
        this.roomNumber = roomNumber;
        this.roomType = roomType;
        this.roomPrice = roomPrice;
        this.roomBalcony = roomBalcony;
        this.roomLounge = roomLounge;
        this.roomReserved = roomReserved;
    }
```

This is the scanner.

```
            while(file.hasNextLine()){
            int roomNumber = file.nextInt();
            String roomType = file.next();
            double roomPrice = file.nextDouble();
            boolean roomBalcony = file.nextBoolean();
            boolean roomLounge = file.nextBoolean();
            boolean roomReserved = false;
            rooms.add(new Room(roomNumber, roomType, roomPrice, roomBalcony, roomLounge, roomReserved));
            file.nextLine();}
        file.close();
```

Comment: What exactly is the issue with the object having ints, doubles, and booleans?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `override` the `toString()` method in your `Room` class and write the implementation for formatted output, e.g.:

```
public class Room {

    int roomNumber;
    String roomType;

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("Room Number : ").append(roomNumber);
        builder.append("\n");
        builder.append("Room Type : ").append(roomType);
        builder.append("\n");
        return builder.toString();
    }
}
```

Once this it's done, you can call `System.out.println` with `Room` object and it will print the output.

Comment: @downvoter any reason for downvote?

Comment: Use the `append` method instead of using `+` when using `StringBuilder`.

Comment: @W-S updated the answer.

Comment: @DarshanMehta Excellent example, thank you very much.